# how to count null field from database in index page in yii php tag

Tags: php, yii

I want to count readdate which must be null in table. I want to fire code in html, there is one table which contains fields like id, storeid, message, readdate, entrydate. If readdate is null then I want to count it and display those counts.

```
<html>
   <div class="orange-count">
      <?php
         echo $unread_recommendation = Storenotification::model()->count("id='" . Yii::app()->session['id'] . "' AND readdate='null' ");
       ?>
   </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql command for NULL count

```
select count(*) from table where column IS NULL;
```

Change it according to your framework.

Comment: i change that but its not working , i can not write query , i have to call model Storenotification nd then i accese my table , i aloso explained my code.

Comment: change . "' AND readdate='null' " => . "' AND readdate IS NULL "

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$count = Storenotification::model()->countByAttributes(array(
                'id'=>Yii::app()->session['id'],
                'readdate' => ""
));
echo $count;
```

This should work too, I haven't tested it though:

```
$count = Storenotification::model()->countByAttributes(array("id"=>Yii::app()->session['id']), "readdate IS NULL OR readdate = ''");
```